# why I am having to create categories or pages everytime - Wordpress.?

Tags: wordpress

In one pc I create categories or pages or any custom fields in wordpress. I commit and push this code. But when I fetch the same in another pc, I 'll have to create all those pages or categories or custom fields again which I created in 1st pc which is a headache and time consuming. Do we need to set anything first time or is there any way to avoid all these. I don't want to create those fields again.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress is not saving the categories, fields, pages as files. It saves them in database. So your commits/push won't work there, you have to update your database as well.